# Installation error in SuiteCRM

Tags: database, sugarcrm, suitecrm

[Click here to see errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2GPr.png)

While installing SuiteCRM on my system, I am getting the errors as shown in above image link. i have Mysql 5.7 installed with php 7 and also enabled mbstring extension in php.ini file. Can anyone suggest me What to do ?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

PHP 7 and MySQL 5.7 is now supported.

## Origional Answer

Currently, SuiteCRM Does not yet fully support MySQL 5.7. MySQL 5.7 strictly follows the SQL 3 Standard. Some features in SuiteCRM utilises MySQL's relaxed standards in prior versions.

To get the best results. Please install MySQL to 5.5 and use PHP 5.6
instead of PHP 7.

Alternatively SuiteCRM can be installed via [bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/suitecrm) which takes care of the requirements for SuiteCRM.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is now supported, starting with version 7.8.x of SuiteCRM.